# Add Client certificate when acting as reverse proxy (Apache/NGINX)

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, certificate

My application makes (POST) requests to an external server (not under my control)

Now this server requires working with client certificates.
My application currently can not handle this (or any time soon).

The idea was to add a reverse proxy.
1) application makes requests to the reverse proxy
2) reverse proxy takes care of client certificate stuff
3) result back to application.

I have no idea how to do (2). Or if it is even possible.

Documentation of NGINX seems to indicate it is impossible.
Documentation of Apache is unclear and difficult to search for. Because I keep getting results for *passing through* the client certificate. Which is not what I need. I need to add a fresh one.

Anyone knows how to do this? (On Apache/NGINX/...)

Comment: Nginx has `proxy_ssl_certificate` and `proxy_ssl_certificate_key`. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html).

Comment: Seems to work perfect. Thanks! If you make it an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nginx proxy module is capable of transmitting a client certificate over an upstream SSL connection.

Use the `proxy_ssl_certificate` and `proxy_ssl_certificate_key` directives to configure it.

See [the manual page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) for details.